# Can you combine a type and a protocol and use that as the base type for an enum?

Tags: swift, enums, protocols

I have a particular pattern of using enums which are always of type String and which the enum (not its raw value) also adheres to a particular protocol. Written normally, this is like so...

```
private enum IndicatorA : String, IndicatorProtocol
{
    case X
    case Y
    case Z
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to find out if there's anything I can do to make the string implied so all I have to type is this...

```
private enum IndicatorA : Indicator
{
    case X
    case Y
    case Z
}
```

... where `Indicator` dictates the raw value is of type `String` and the enum itself also adheres to the `IndicatorProtocol` protocol.

I've tried both of these to come up with something to use as the raw value's type, but neither compiles. Plus, technically that puts the protocol on the string, not the enum, so that isn't what I'm after anyway. (Again, I want the protocol on the enum, not the raw value.)

```
class Indicator : String, IndicatorProtocol
{
}

struct Indicator : String, IndicatorProtocol
{
}
```

So is there any way to do what I'm trying to achieve in either Swift 2.x or 3.x? Perhaps with constraints on the protocol somehow?

Comment: Only `String`, `Character` or any integer or floating point type can be the raw value of an enumeration, so I don't see how this could work. And you cannot  subclass value types (like `String`). – Perhaps someone proves me wrong!

Comment: In addition, I believe that the raw value type indication is a privileged part of the declaration. Note that it has to come at the beginning of the inheritance list.

Comment: Yeah, I'm relying on it being a string. I just want it to also adhere to that protocol.  Not that big a deal if I have to type `String, Protocol` but I'd love to simplify it if possible.

Comment: @MarqueIV: "I just want it to also adhere to that protocol". What is the "it" that you are referring to? The raw value type, or the enumeration itself?

Comment: The enumeration.  When you assign a protocol to the enumeration, the enumeration becomes 'self' in static methods whereas the individual case statements become 'self' in non-static methods.  For instance, in the protocol, I define a non-static `var rawValue:String { get }` which returns the raw value of that enumeration's case.  I need that raw value to be a string, hence defining the enum itself with a string.  There's an extension on that protocol that does something with that string value.

Answer (score 1):

A couple thoughts on this:

Assuming it's possible to make the enum contain an `Indicator` as its raw value, it's important to note that this would not actually make the enum itself conform to the `IndicatorProtocol`, only its rawValue would conform.  In other words:

```
enum IndicatorA : String, IndicatorProtocol
```

is not the same thing as:

```
enum IndicatorA : StringThatConformsToIndicatorProtocol
```

For the first example, you could access the protocol like this:

```
let example:IndicatorA = IndicatorA(rawValue:"Test")
example.someProtocolMethod()
```

For the second example, you would have to access the protocol like this:

```
let example:IndicatorA = IndicatorA(rawValue:"Test")
example.rawValue.someProtocolMethod()
```

because in the first example the enum itself is conforming to the protocol, but in the second example, the enum's raw value is conforming to the protocol.

**All that said**, you could sort of make the second example work by create an `Indicator` struct that conforms to `StringLiteralConvertible`, `Equatable` and your own `IndicatorProtocol`. Example:

```
protocol IndicatorProtocol {
    func printHello()
}

struct Indicator: IndicatorProtocol, StringLiteralConvertible, Equatable {
    let string: String
    init(name value: String) {
        self.string = value
    }

    init(stringLiteral value: String) {
        self.string = value
    }

    init(extendedGraphemeClusterLiteral value: String) {
        self.string = value
    }

    init(unicodeScalarLiteral value: String) {
        self.string = value
    }

    func printHello() {
        print("Hello from \(string)")
    }
}

func ==(left:Indicator, right:Indicator) -> Bool {
    return left.string == right.string

}

enum IndicatorA : Indicator {
    case One = "One", Two = "Two"
}

let test = IndicatorA.One

print(test.rawValue.printHello())   // prints "Hello from One
```

But that's a good bit of extra work to achieve a result that is not what I think you were hoping for in the first place!

Comment: I'm on a train typing this on my mobile, but the short version is no, I am not making Indicator the raw value. I want String to be the raw value.  I *also* want the *enum* to conform to a protocol, which has extensions also expecting the rawValue to be a string.  So again, I want String, Protocol, but I'm trying to find if I can make Strings inferred. Make sense?

Comment: i.e. your first example.  I am not making the raw value conform to anything.  Also, I'm actually using the default raw values which are string representations of the case statements.

Comment: @MarqueIV  Ah, I understand. I'm not aware of any way to typealias an enum raw value plus a protocol to conform to into a single type.

Comment: I updated my question for more clarity.  Your comments highlighted how I wasn't being clear enough.  Hopefully it now is.  Thanks for trying though! :)